# Can overlapping videos from 2 or more sources be merged in real time for live feed?

Tags: live-recording

We would like to make a real time live feed from the front of our house with different cameras.
The final output is meant to be as follows but with more resolution.

[image]

The setup was thought to be static (cameras are not moving) from different points on the same plane (same distance to the house, just translated along the pathway). This would create a panoramical view of the front part where each camera would record a specific region:

[image]

The reason behind using several cameras and not sime 360º ones is that the result would not besatisfactory as: 
1) point of view is unique so the distance from the viewer would not be the same to the front, avoiding the paronamic view we are looking for 
2) The image would be a little bit deformed 
3) Apart from being messy to move around, the would record stuff we don't want (such as the opposite of the street) increasing also the bitrate of the stream.

On the other hand, as cameras are fixed, we thought about using some fixed sincronizing/ recognition elements, such as the ones used in QR or AR, in order to delimit the area for each camera.

[image]

Additionally, to avoid excessive (and unused) bitrate but also focusing on the experience, we thought about the option of focusing on one particular area, inspite of creating the full video, only the interested part would be displayed. We have not yet decided between selecting us the area or led the user to do it (dont know the complexity of this or if it is even possible)

[image]

Although we have some experience in editing videos and even with opencv, this questions are completely out of our range. We have found software such as OBS but we did not find a possive or negative answer to our questions (it might be we are lacking the precise term).

**Our questions are**:

1) Would this be possible in real time?

2) What would the optimal solution be? SW vs SW+HW-wise.

3) Provided it is possible, would the processing be too intense to have a fluid, smooth and as real as possible? We are afraid that the delay would be too high.

4) Would the real time area selection be factible? We suppose that selecting an area of the video should be trivial but mdifying that selection on the flight is the trick.

Comment: It sounds like you're taking a difficult approach to a problem with a simple answer.  Placing a single camera further from the subject and using a longer focal length lens will remove the distortion you're talking about.  It is certainly *possible* to do what you're asking; car manufacturers stitch together multiple cameras to provide top-down "backup cams," but they make custom hardware and software to do it.  What kind of budget are you talking about?  A home hobbyist, or a Ring competitor with VC funding?

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking your time to answer the question.

We thought about the lens, but it made all too small for our purposes. Although, we might rethink this approach with a better camera (right now it is not cuttng edge technology). Regarding the budget, it is not quite high (less than 6000$). Nevertheless, would the other questions be possible with this budget?